# Enabling GWT logs in browser console in production - overhead?

Tags: gwt

I would like to enable some trace logs in my GWT app in production mode. The logs are written to the browser console and triggered by every user operation.

I wonder if this may cause problems such as increasing browser's memory or may even cause a crash? Does supported browsers keep maximum limit of log history, or should I take care of it?

I'm using java.util.logging.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'd better only activate it when needed. Use a `property-provider` to switch between 2 permutations: the one by default without logging, and another one with logging enabled.

Comment: This sounds great - but if I decide to keep them up for a while, would that cause a problem in the browser?
And about the property-value: can you supply an example or some resource I can look at? Thanks!

Comment: I use the console logging and I can't notice any deley when using it. Also the browsers only log to the console when needed (browser feature) so I think you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks! And about overflow for logs? Does the browser handle it (limit the history of the logger or w/e...)?